# OSX Disk Arbitration linker errors

Tags: c++, macos, linker-errors

Trying to compile my C++ application using clang which works but I get the following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_DADiskCopyDescription", referenced from:
  Security::getHddID() in Security.cpp.o
"_DADiskCreateFromBSDName", referenced from:
  Security::getHddID() in Security.cpp.o
"_DASessionCreate", referenced from:
  Security::getHddID() in Security.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I've checked the official documentation for Disk Arbitration on the Apple website but that's awful, since it doesn't even tell you which library file to include, let alone what to link to.

I'm using CMake to set up my build chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `-framework DiskArbitration` in your linker arguments.